# Detection if image path contains string fails

Tags: conditionals, characters, strings, comparison

For a project I would like to check if my included image is located in the sub-folder `graphs` or not. To check that I wrote a small MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsfonts,
floatfix,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
pra,
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{substr}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
    \def\textendash{-}%
    \filename@parse{#1}%
    \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
    \filename@base
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\instringTF}{mmmm}
{
    \oleks_instring:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
}

\tl_new:N \l__oleks_instring_test_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \oleks_instring:nnnn
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l__oleks_instring_test_tl { #1 }
    \regex_match:nnTF { \u{l__oleks_instring_test_tl} } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \LetLtxMacro{\includegraphicsorig}{\includegraphics}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{} m }{%
        \filename@parse{#2}%
        \IfSubStr{\expandafter\detokenize{\filename@area}}{\detokenize{graph}}{Path \filename@area contains graph}{Path \filename@area does not contain graph}%
%       \IfSubStringInString{\detokenize{graph}}{\filename@area}{Path \filename@area contains graph}{Path \filename@area does not contain graph}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{graphs/sub.tikz}
        \caption{Image I}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Image II}
    \end{figure}
    \IfSubStr{graphs/}{graphs}{Contains graphs}{Does not contain graph}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the function in the re-defined version of `includegraphics` always evaluates to `false`, while the function located in the body itself evaluates to `true`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expandafter\detokenize{`

expands a `{` which is not expandable, you intended

`\detokenize\expandafter{`

to expand the token after `{`

Comment: Hmm, that was easy, I could have thought about that myself. Thanks!